# Vqmod not displayed into the admin panel In Opencart

Tags: opencart

I have Installed the Open cart Version 1.5.2.1, Every thing is working fine and I have Installed the Vqmod module in it. It is installed correctly and overwrites the index.php as well as the admin/index.php and generated the files in vqcache but I could not see vqmod manager in the admin panel, Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I do not understand why would one install more than a year old version 1.5.2 when there is the latest 1.5.4.1 available (to the date of December 21, 2012).

Comment: @shadyyx - The latest isn't always the most stable. With each version comes new bugs that need fixing so just because the latest version is available doesn't mean it's the better one. I know people on versions back as far as 1.3.1 - that was well before I even heard of OC :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is pretty simple. vQmod manager is ***not*** part of the vQmod download, nor the OpenCart package. It's a separate installation that you need to do after those. It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2969).

Comment: I thought the same at first, but this line threw me off "...I have Installed the Vqmod **module** in it". Let's see if you nailed it.

Comment: @B-and-P Yep, he installed `vQmod`, not the `vQmod Manager`, read the question and answer once more ;-)

Comment: Exactly...I maintain vQmod with Qphoria...vQmod manager on the other hand is maintained by an OpenCart forum member called RPH (Ryan)

Comment: @shadyyx Yeah, I read it ok the first time :) The word `module` threw me off.

Comment: @JayGlifford Kudos for the great work on vQmod to you and Q, also for all the Opencart support you and shaddyx provide here on SO.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I have solved the problem and now its working well.